# Staining mid to low quality wood

Tags: staining, plywood

100% novice zero experience with wood

Building a day bed for a campervan... I didn't have the biggest budget for materials. I bought a 5 layer bcx plywood and premium stud 2x4s to work with.

I sanded them and am ready to assemble, but I'd like to seal the wood somehow, but I don't like the idea or look of painting. I have several questions... But I guess I should ask first.

Should I assemble the piece first or stain the wood first?

Thanks in advance for any insights into the pproject!!!

Comment: You have a lot of questions, but I'd say the Poly is all you need and you can apply it before or after assembly.

Comment: Welcome to [woodworking.se], please take the [tour]. You have too many questions here - we work on a one-question per post basis. Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit] your question down to just one. Feel free to [ask](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as many new questions as you'd like - nobody here will look down on you. Also, please be sure to search the site as a lot of this info is already covered here.

Comment: Sorry, I'll change it.... I will be likely good if the just poly anewer is okay though!

Comment: *"100% novice zero experience with wood Building a day bed for a campervan..."* Are you following a plan or guide online? Because if you're not and have literally zero experience then you might want to pause right there. It is perfectly doable for a first-timer to make a simple project from construction wood and ply — that's how and when many simple workbenches get made :-) — but you're unlikely to be able to build something decently robust without at least *some* knowledge of basic construction methods and principles. So highly advise you don't just wing it IF that was the plan.

Comment: Oh I'm going from a plan for sure!! I put my research into learning the why of how the bed was made by asking others who have followed this particular plan before. The designer was kind enough to upload the detailed plans for the bed including all of the measurements and fasteners used. Then I took my time to familiarize myself with the fastners and why things are used. I don't have construction experience but I have some general knowledge of tools from car repairs(I do basic tune up/brakes level work).

Comment: Good to hear you're following a plan, that'll take all the guesswork out of it. Best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to seal the wood somehow

Prior to the edit you mention you have some waterbased poly and that would be fine for this. It will minimally change the colour of the materials you're using.

Not every surface needs to have finish applied — if you look at existing wooden furniture you'll see that finish is often skipped for non-show surfaces.

I'd recommend you use at least two coats everywhere you do apply the poly, mainly because just one coat of almost every finish rarely looks perfectly uniform. Add more coats on any surface that you envisage experiencing more wear, up to perhaps a maximum of four.

**Note on curing:** it's important to let the finish cure before putting an item into service because only after full cure is a finish as tough and, importantly in this context, non-tacky as it can be. The on-pack instructions or the manufacturer's product page should give you an idea on how long this will take, but a good rough rule of thumb is about a month. If something must be put into service before then one should wait a full week at minimum before *light* use.

> Should I assemble the piece first or stain the wood first?

Whether to finish parts or all of a project prior to assembly is very much a personal preference, often driven by the nature of the project.

For example it's not uncommon to pre-finish *parts* of a bookshelf or cabinet prior to building, for various practical reasons, but much rarer for a table because its simpler construction doesn't benefit from it as much.

**About stain here**
There's absolutely no requirement to stain wood, unless you specifically want to change the colour. That is stain's one and only job.

Please be aware that both cheap ply and construction wood are not noted for staining well if stained conventionally. "Gel stain", as you were originally thinking of using, is probably the best product for colouring projects made from both of the materials you've bought..... assuming you don't want to paint.

Comment: Thank you for all of this ineo. I think I will go with just the poly coating, but I was surprised to hear you say it might take a month for the wood to be ready for daily use. I was hoping to do the coating today, and have the bed put together two days later....

Comment: A water-based poly should dry enough for light use much more quickly.

Comment: @gnicko, for light use, absolutely. I cover that. As for full cure of waterbased finishes in general, it's a surprise to users that it can take far far longer than one might feel is same to assume based on the extremely fast touch-dry time. Additionally it is not at all rare to experience a finish hardening more slowly than stated, because so few of us finish in a space that matches the ideal application conditions the manufacturers list, with both higher RH and lower temperature being major contributing factors (esp. if encountered together) as well as the effect of lower airflow.

Comment: I would consider finishing _all_ surfaces for something that's going in a camper van. The interior is far less climate controlled than the inside of a house would be, and allowing some non-show surfaces (like the back side, up against an uninsulated, metal exterior wall) could get moist from condensation (that's never even noticed) and start that rotting out. You may not notice the rot on the back side until you flop down, exhausted, one evening only to have the bed flop all the way down to the floor with you... The little time, effort & material it takes provides an extra level of insurance.

Comment: @FreeMan, good point, I hadn't fully considered this specific use-case.